# Borel-Cantelli and almost sure convergence: Both events occur infintely often

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas, bernoulli-distribution

Let $(X_n)_n$ a sequence of i.i.d random variables $\sim \operatorname{Ber}(1/n)$, i. e. $P(X=1)=1/n$ and $P(X=0)=1-1/n$.

My question: Using Borel-Cantelli, I can show that both $\{X_n=1\}_n$ and $\{X_n=0\}_n$ will occur infinetly many times. I think this contradicts the almost sure convergence. But can this really happen? Can both events occur infintely many often? Is this like $\infty+\infty=\infty$?

Comment: It can definitely happen. You don't have almost sure convergence here.

Comment: Thank you. Just wanted to cross-check.

Comment: As a side remark (everything else is fine), notice that those are not i.i.d. random variables.